# Case statement not supporting horizontal search with column name in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to ORACLE SQL and I am trying to learn it quickly.
I have following table definition:

```
Create table Sales_Biodata
(
Saler_Id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Jan_Sales INTEGER NOT NULL,
Feb_Sales INTEGER NOT NULL,
March_Sales INTEGER NOT NULL
);

Insert into Sales_Biodata  (SALER_ID,JAN_SALES,Feb_Sales,March_Sales)
values ('101',22,525,255);
Insert into Sales_Biodata  (SALER_ID,JAN_SALES,Feb_Sales,March_Sales)
values ('102',22,55,25);
Insert into Sales_Biodata  (SALER_ID,JAN_SALES,Feb_Sales,March_Sales)
values ('103',45545,5125,2865);
```

My objective is the following:
1- Searching the highest sales and second highest sales against each saler_id.
For example in our above case:
For saler_id =101 highest sales is 525 and second highest sales is 255
similary for saler_id=102 highest sales is 55 and second highest sales is 25

For my above approach I am using the following query:

```
Select Saler_Id,
(
CASE
WHEN JAN_SALES>FEB_SALES AND JAN_SALES>MARCH_SALES THEN JAN_SALES
WHEN FEB_SALES>JAN_SALES AND FEB_SALES>MARCH_SALES THEN FEB_SALES
WHEN MARCH_SALES>JAN_SALES AND MARCH_SALES>FEB_SALES THEN MARCH_SALES
WHEN JAN_SALES=FEB_SALES AND JAN_SALES=MARCH_SALES THEN JAN_SALES
WHEN JAN_SALES=FEB_SALES AND JAN_SALES>MARCH_SALES THEN JAN_SALES
WHEN JAN_SALES=MARCH_SALES AND JAN_SALES>FEB_SALES THEN JAN_SALES
WHEN FEB_SALES=JAN_SALES AND FEB_SALES>MARCH_SALES THEN FEB_SALES
WHEN FEB_SALES=MARCH_SALES AND FEB_SALES>JAN_SALES THEN FEB_SALES
WHEN MARCH_SALES=JAN_SALES AND MARCH_SALES>FEB_SALES THEN MARCH_SALES
WHEN MARCH_SALES=FEB_SALES AND MARCH_SALES>JAN_SALES THEN MARCH_SALES
ELSE 'NEW_CASE_FOUND'
END
) FIRST_HIGHEST,
(
CASE
WHEN JAN_SALES>FEB_SALES AND FEB_SALES>MARCH_SALES THEN FEB_SALES
WHEN FEB_SALES>JAN_SALES AND JAN_SALES>MARCH_SALES THEN JAN_SALES
WHEN JAN_SALES>MARCH_SALES AND MARCH_SALES>FEB_SALES THEN MARCH_SALES
ELSE 'NEW_CASE_FOUND'
END
) SECOND_HIGHEST
from
Sales_Biodata;
```

but I am getting the following errors:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 60 Column: 6
```

Please guide me on the following:
1- How to search the data horizontally for maximum and second maximum.
2- Please guide me on alternate approaches for searching data for a row horizontally.

Comment: Look at your `ELSE`.  It is a string.  You need to convert the other values to strings as well, perhaps using `to_char()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff did you mean `to_char()`?

Comment: Nitpick: `Saler_Id` should probably be `Seller_Id`

Comment: If you're new to SQL (and relational databases) then I strongly recommend looking into normalisation.

Comment: This would be a lot simpler if you changed your data model to have a table with `seller_id, sales_month, sales_value`, so one row per salesman per month. Something to ask yourself is how you'll store more than one year's worth of data, or how you'll tackle other more complicated queries. (You might indeed benefit from understanding [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)).

Comment: @GordonLinoff is there any other approach for horizontal searching since after such long hour of research my query is still not working and lot of concurrent cases exist which making the query too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model is wrong.
The first thing I would do is to unpivot data using this query:

```
select * from sales_biodata
unpivot (
  val for mon in ( JAN_SALES,FEB_SALES,MARCH_SALES )
)
;
```

and after this, getting two top values is relatively easy:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, 
          dense_rank() over (partition by saler_id order by val desc ) x
    FROM (
        select * from sales_biodata
        unpivot (
          val for mon in ( JAN_SALES,FEB_SALES,MARCH_SALES )
        )
    ) t
)
WHERE x <= 2
```

the above query will give a result in this format:

```
 SALER_ID MON                VAL          X
---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
       101 FEB_SALES          525          1 
       101 MARCH_SALES        255          2 
       102 FEB_SALES           55          1 
       102 MARCH_SALES         25          2 
       103 JAN_SALES        45545          1 
       103 FEB_SALES         5125          2
```

If you have more month than 3 months, you can easily extend this query changing this part:
`val for mon in ( JAN_SALES,FEB_SALES,MARCH_SALES, April_sales, MAY_SALES, JUNE_SALES, JULY_SALES, ...... NOVEMBER_SALES, DECEMBER_SALES )`
If you want both two values in one row, you need to pivot data back:

```
WITH src_data AS(
    SELECT saler_id, val, x 
    FROM (
        SELECT t.*, 
              dense_rank() over (partition by saler_id order by val desc ) x
        FROM (
            select * from sales_biodata
            unpivot (
              val for mon in ( JAN_SALES,FEB_SALES,MARCH_SALES )
            )
        ) t
    )
    WHERE x <= 2
)
SELECT *
FROM src_data
PIVOT(
      max(val) FOR x IN ( 1 As "First value", 2 As "Second value" )
);
```

This gives a result in this form:

```
  SALER_ID First value Second value
---------- ----------- ------------
       101         525          255 
       102          55           25 
       103       45545         5125
```

---

**EDIT - why `MAX` is used in the PIVOT query**

---

The short answer is: because the syntax reuires an aggregate function here.
See this link for the syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#CHDCEJJE
[image]

---

A broader answer:
The PIVOT clause is only a syntactic sugar that simplifies a general "classic" pivot query which is using aggregate function and `GROUP BY` clause, like this:

```
SELECT id,
       max( CASE WHEN some_column = 'X' THEN value END ) As x,
       max( CASE WHEN some_column = 'Y' THEN value END ) As y,
       max( CASE WHEN some_column = 'Z' THEN value END ) As z
FROM table11
GROUP BY id
```

More on PIVOT queries you can find on the net, there is a lot of excelent explanations how the pivot query works.
The above pivot query, written in "standard" SQL, is equivalent to this Oracle's query:

```
SELECT *
FROM table11
PIVOT (
  max(value) FOR some_column IN ( 'X', 'Y', 'Z' )
)
```

These PIVOT queries transform records like this:

```
        ID SOME_COLUMN      VALUE
---------- ----------- ----------
         1 X                  10 
         1 X                  15 
         1 Y                  20 
         1 Z                  30
```

into one record (for each `id`) like this:

```
        ID        'X'        'Y'        'Z'
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1         15         20         30
```

Please note, that the source table contains two values for id=1 and some_column='X' -> 10 and 15. PIVOT queries uses aggregate function to support that "general" case, where there could be many source records for one record in the output. In this example 'MAX' function is used to pick greater value 15.
However PIVOT queries supports also your specific case where there is only one source record for each value in the result.

Comment: thanks :) Its a very good query I will try to understand the concepts and logics of your query , Currently i don't have 15 points so i cannot upvote but i will upvote your answer once i will receive that point. Accepting your answer :)

Comment: could you please provide little explanation of statement max(val) FOR x IN ( 1 As "First value", 2 As "Second value" ) your query,like 1- placeholder 1 AS "First Value" and 2 "Second Value" is clear to me that you are taking all dense rank 1 as first values and so on but WHY YOU HAD USED MAX(VAL)??

Comment: I've added an explanation to the answer why 'MAX' is used in pivot queries.

Comment: Thanks :) your explanation provided me lifetime understanding of this concept :)

Answer (score 4):

Getting the maximum value is simply:

```
select greatest(jan_sales, feb_sales, mar_sales)
```

If you want the second value:

```
select (case when jan_sales = greatest(jan_sales, feb_sales, mar_sales)
             then greatest(feb_sales, mar_sales)
             when feb_sales = greatest(jan_sales, feb_sales, mar_sales)
             then greatest(jan_sales, mar_sales)
             else greatest(jan_sales, feb_sales)
         end)
```

However, this is the wrong approach to the whole problem.  The main issues is that you have the wrong data structure.  Store values in *rows* not *columns*.  So, you need to unpivot your data and re-aggregation, such as:

```
select saler_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then sales end) as sales_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then sales end) as sales_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then sales end) as sales_3
from (select s.*, dense_rank() over (partition by saler_id order by sales desc) as seqnum
      from (select saler_id, jan_sales as sales Sales_Biodata union all
            select saler_id, feb_sales Sales_Biodata union all
            select saler_id, mar_sales Sales_Biodata
           ) s
     ) s
group by saler_id;
```

Comment: your third query is very complex i am unable to understand like what is seqnum there and why you have max function and  you have used subquery with in subquery i am trying to understand it but could you please explain purpose of seqnum and max(case when seqnum=1....) a little

Answer (score 1):

You are coming across the error as the string 'new case found' is added in the else part and the rest of the case statement deals with number . data type in the when and else clause should match.
Coming to alternate approaches you may use unpivot and get the months sales data into a single row and use analytical functions to get the 1st highest or second highest.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the problem is that the `WHEN` clauses in your `CASE` statement are returning `INTEGER` values, but the `ELSE` is returning a character string. I completely agree with the comments regarding normalization but if you really just want to make this query work you'll need to convert the results of each `WHEN` clause to character, as in:

```
Select Saler_Id,
(
CASE
WHEN JAN_SALES>FEB_SALES AND JAN_SALES>MARCH_SALES THEN TO_CHAR(JAN_SALES)
WHEN FEB_SALES>JAN_SALES AND FEB_SALES>MARCH_SALES THEN TO_CHAR(FEB_SALES)
WHEN MARCH_SALES>JAN_SALES AND MARCH_SALES>FEB_SALES THEN TO_CHAR(MARCH_SALES)
WHEN JAN_SALES=FEB_SALES AND JAN_SALES=MARCH_SALES THEN TO_CHAR(JAN_SALES)
WHEN JAN_SALES=FEB_SALES AND JAN_SALES>MARCH_SALES THEN TO_CHAR(JAN_SALES)
WHEN JAN_SALES=MARCH_SALES AND JAN_SALES>FEB_SALES THEN TO_CHAR(JAN_SALES)
WHEN FEB_SALES=JAN_SALES AND FEB_SALES>MARCH_SALES THEN TO_CHAR(FEB_SALES)
WHEN FEB_SALES=MARCH_SALES AND FEB_SALES>JAN_SALES THEN TO_CHAR(FEB_SALES)
WHEN MARCH_SALES=JAN_SALES AND MARCH_SALES>FEB_SALES THEN TO_CHAR(MARCH_SALES)
WHEN MARCH_SALES=FEB_SALES AND MARCH_SALES>JAN_SALES THEN TO_CHAR(MARCH_SALES)
ELSE 'NEW_CASE_FOUND'
END
) FIRST_HIGHEST,
(
CASE
WHEN JAN_SALES>FEB_SALES AND FEB_SALES>MARCH_SALES THEN TO_CHAR(FEB_SALES)
WHEN FEB_SALES>JAN_SALES AND JAN_SALES>MARCH_SALES THEN TO_CHAR(JAN_SALES)
WHEN JAN_SALES>MARCH_SALES AND MARCH_SALES>FEB_SALES THEN TO_CHAR(MARCH_SALES)
ELSE 'NEW_CASE_FOUND'
END
) SECOND_HIGHEST
from
Sales_Biodata;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks I will try to become expert in oracle in coming years :)